# How to Get Address tag or JSON value from Any website using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

Here is the JSON Format code, How can I extract from a website.
I want to Extract all data from which is below. Is this possible in Selenium or not ? Any other possible solutions using JSONObject?

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context":"http://schema.org",
          "@type":"LocalBusiness",
          "name":"CompanyName",
          "address":{
            "@type":"PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress":"171, Madison Avenue, Suite 1006",
            "addressLocality":"New York",

        "addressRegion":"NY",
        "postalCode":"10016",
        "addressCountry":"US"
      },
      "geo":{
        "@type":"GeoCoordinates",
        "latitude":40.7474322,
        "longitude":-73.9831712
      },
      "url":"http://www.CompanyName.com/",
      "telephone":"+12126856060",
      "openingHoursSpecification":[
        {
          "@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification",
          "dayOfWeek":[
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday"
          ],
          "opens":"00:00",
          "closes":"23:59"
        },
      {
        "@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification",
        "dayOfWeek":[
          "Saturday",
          "Sunday"
        ],
        "opens":"00:00",
        "closes":"00:00"
      }
      ]
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: It is possible to parse these as a JSONObject . How do you extract this text? just driver.source?

Comment: Thank for this Suggestion: **"It is possible to parse these as a JSONObject"**.

Comment: **How do you extract this text? just driver.source?** Working on IT. I am also finding the solution